# automatic date picking selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on automating some web related task. For that I am using selenium. However, After trying hours I could not figure out to automate date picking. I have two calendars. See the figure to understand better.

[[image: calendars to pick1]

What I am trying to achieve is to choose two dates from the left and right calendar. I want to send two dates and set those dates( also month and year) on those two calendars. I tried to do something like that. I took the xpath for "k-calendar k-first-month" class.

```
calender_left = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="filter-section-timeFilters"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]')
         
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(calender_left).click().send_keys('02/12/20').perform()
```

However, no luck on that.

This is how the css elements looks like for the left calendar.
[image]

Update: I decided to click month and year button using xPath.

Comment: The element where you're sending keys is not visible on the screenshot. You haven't explained what problem exactly do you have. What is the end result of your actions? Some kind of error? Your locator is unmaintainable and unreadable  - you should be cautious about locator verbosity (don't use absolute xPaths). Html source will be more useful that this screen

Comment: @PiotrM. 
Thanks a lot for the feed back. My current code does nothing, also there is no error. I took the xpath of "k-calender k-first-month" class of the div.

Comment: It does not work like that :) You can send keys to input element. Otherwise, you have to prepare more complex code to select date. Am I right that page uses Kendo JQuery? Could you provide the url or source code of the page?

Comment: I have already solved the problem. I used xPaths to go  back and forth and pick dates. 
However, I appreciate the effort and intend to help me :) This was lot of if else conditions ... :(

Comment: I can imagine, I've been working on automating kendo datepicker, it is quite complex widget. Hmm, you can check out this project to improve your work:
https://github.com/atata-framework/atata-kendoui

Answer (score 0):

Is there any input field to enter date through keyboard?

If YES take `xPath or clasName or cssSelector` of that element and use `sendkeys`.
Refer the link https://www.browserstack.com/guide/datepicker-in-selenium it will be helpfull.

Comment: Unfortunately no input field to enter date through keyboard. date selection only through clicking and selecting the date. So, are you saying if there is no input field to enter date then there is no way to automate the process ?

Comment: No. Not like that. We can do it through clicking the data. Just follow the reference links mentioned below
1. https://www.guru99.com/handling-date-time-picker-using-selenium.html
2. https://www.browserstack.com/guide/datepicker-in-selenium
Hope it will be helpful.